# How do I use Nokogiri to parse row by row using CSS selectors?

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri, mechanize

I have an HTML table I'd like to parse.  I want to move down each `<TR>` and extract the href.
The HTML looks like this:

```
table id="classified_table" class="vs-classified-table widget-off top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td id="classified_cell">
    <table class="vs-classified-table widget-off" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr id="vs_classified_73634384" class="classified row1 kiwii-clad-row kiwii-clad-featured">
    <tr id="vs_classified_74530668" class="classified row2 kiwii-clad-row kiwii-clad-featured">
    <tr id="vs_classified_62296263" class="classified row3 kiwii-clad-row kiwii-clad-featured">
    <tr id="vs_classified_62468547" class="classified row4 kiwii-clad-row kiwii-clad-featured">
    <tr id="vs_classified_47122034" class="classified row5 kiwii-clad-row kiwii-clad-featured">
    <tr id="vs_classified_78210646" class="classified row6 kiwii-clad-row">
    <tr id="vs_classified_78207083" class="classified row7 kiwii-clad-row">
    <tr id="vs_classified_69104369" class="classified row8 kiwii-clad-row">
    <tr id="vs_classified_78113204" class="classified row9 kiwii-clad-row">
    <tr id="vs_classified_52761813" class="classified row10 kiwii-clad-row">
    <tr id="vs_classified_78121746" class="classified row11 kiwii-clad-row">
    <tr id="vs_classified_76515548" class="classified row12 kiwii-clad-row">
    <tr id="vs_advert_middle" class="vs-advertisement advertisment-middle-2 vs-adsense-middle-BR-" style="border:none">
    <tr id="vs_classified_34048811" class="classified row13 kiwii-clad-row">
```

My Ruby code looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://servico-informatica.vivanuncios.com/computador+rio-de-janeiro-capital/'))
rows = page.css('tr#vs_classified_73634384.classified td.summary div a#vs-detail-link-1.kiwii-clear-none')
puts rows.text
#this works

rows [1..10].each do |row|
    puts "this isn't working :("

end
```

The first print successfully prints the text of the first `<TR>`, but the `puts` inside the `each` loop doesn't work.

The page I'm trying to scrape is: http://servico-informatica.vivanuncios.com/computador+rio-de-janeiro-capital/

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are looking for in terms of output?  Like do you want an array of only the links?  do you want the text in the links? etc..

Comment: Your HTML sample is invalid and missing the HREFs, and you haven't specified which HREFs you are interested in in the link.

Answer (score 3):

You are receiving only one result because your css query is using the `#` which means it is looking for a unique element on the page([Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors)).

So you need to modify the query to look for href's based on the the css class.

```
tr.classified td.summary a.classified-link
```

**Update**

The above css path will grab all of the links, then you just need to walk through the array and do what you need to with the href and text.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://servico-informatica.vivanuncios.com/computador+rio-de-janeiro-capital/'))
links = page.css("tr.classified td.summary a.classified-link")

links.map do |link|
  puts link['href']
  puts link.content
end
```

Comment: Actually, nokogiri doesn't care about the spec. If there's 2 elements with the same id, `css` will return both.

Comment: a fair enough, well it is still only grabbing a single element because the page is creating unique id's

Comment: so what's the best way to go about it?  Point at the tbody, and then create another variable which points to the TR, and then loop?

Comment: I want to go through every TR and scrap the text, and link.  What's the best way way of pointing Nokogiri?  At the Tbody?
Could you show me how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're expecting this to do:

```
rows [1..10].each do |row|
  puts "this isn't working :("
end
```

but I'm pretty sure it won't do what you're expecting it to do. That's actually interpreted as this:

```
rows[1..10].each { ... }
```

and since the `rows` (which is a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`) only has one entry, trying to [extract a subset](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-5B-5D) starting at `1` gives you an empty [`NodeSet`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html); that means that you're effectively just saying this:

```
some_empty_node_set.each { ... }
```

and that does nothing useful. However, if you look at the first entry in `rows`, you'll find the `href` you're looking for:

```
rows[0]['href']
# "http://servico-informatica.vivanuncios.com/..."
```

You could also look at `rows.attr('href')` or `rows.first['href']` depending on taste and what fits your needs.

Comment: The "puts this isn't working" was just there to make sure my code was working up until that point.

Your speculation as to what im trying to do isn't that far off :)
Im trying to get the text, and href of every entry (<TR>)

Could you show me what to select with the CSS Path?